# Minimal Asterisk installation on Debian

Tags: debian, asterisk

I'm trying to install Asterisk using Debian 9's package on my home-server (argh... unprofessional user, I'm sorry).

But well, the dependencies are really astonishing, `asterisk-modules` needs a lot of extra-packages (debtree creates a really, really huge chart). Well that package contains hardly all asterisk-modules. But as I want to use just a very limited set of Asterisk's modules and being a big fan of having a minimal set of software on my machine, I only want to install the "core" of asterisk.

Is there any way of doing this with Debian? I know, that it is possible to specify the loaded modules. But I don't even want to install those dependencies. I could build Asterisk from source, but I am not keen on doing security updates by hand.

Have I missed anything to achieve this kind of minimal installation?

Comment: Yes but among them is GTK2, ATK, Harfbuzz and the XRandr2... I don't want them on my server, but maybe I'm a bit too minimalistic...

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is the right place for unprofessional users. I don't see anything gtk in the debtree report. I do see xrandr though, and it looks like it's a hard depends path unfortunately.